# How to load Jmeter 2.11's JTL file in Jmeter 2.13

Tags: jmeter

I have upgraded JMeter version from 2.11 to 2.13. I am able to run the test. But I could not load 2.11's JTL test results into latest version 2.13.

I have noticed that two additional fields introduced in JTL file which I executed the test from JMeter 2.13. Do we have any properties to changes this?

Anyone can you please help how to load JTL file that executed in Jmeter 2.11 version into Jmeter 2.13 version?

I got below error in jmeter.log.

2015/12/16 16:15:29 INFO  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: {Actual JTL File Name} does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration. 
2015/12/16 16:15:29 WARN  - jmeter.save.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'allThreads' at line 1 
2015/12/16 16:15:29 WARN  - jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: {Actual JTL File Name}

Comment: Check properties in `saveservice.properties` to modify JTL file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Bug 57025](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57025) since JMeter 2.12 number of active threads in current thread group and in general is being stored into results file by default. So in order to open results files generated by older JMeter versions you need to turn this off. There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Permanent: add the following line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
2. Temporary: pass aforementioned property to JMeter via -J command line argument as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about different JMeter properties types and ways of working with them.